# Setting full width background image for the header in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My question is how can i set full width and height background image for the header in Bootstrap like `http://demo.evenfly.com/view?theme=SantaGo` ( i am not expecting animations, i am expecting how to make background that fits in to screen like this)?

This is what i have done so far,

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/reYRBo

**HTML:**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="sltac.css">
  </head>
<body>
<header>
<div class="row">
<div class="bg-image" id="jumboid">
<img src="http://www.visitnorwich.co.uk/assets/Uploads/Events-images/Theatre-generic.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="Cinque Terre" width="100%" height="40%" back> 
</div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}

#jumboid{
    width:100% ;

}

.bg-image {
    position: relative;
}
.bg-image img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1200px; /* corresponds to max height of 450px */
    margin: 0 auto;

}

header{
     width:100%;
  height:100%;
  height:calc(100% - 1px);
  background-image:url('a.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
}
```

At the end i'm expecting the result like this(if i take full page screen shot),

[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbaH1.png)

Comment: Something like this? http://www.bootply.com/108614

Comment: i think the following css is enough for your requirement.you don't have to write any other css.
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

Comment: @Stuart yeah, i tried that before, but image is not responsive :/

Comment: its set to cover, so it will always scale :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to use an extra image tag. Just set the background and the property `background-size: cover`

Try it like this:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://www.visitnorwich.co.uk/assets/Uploads/Events-images/Theatre-generic.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <header>

  </header>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have an `img` tag inside the `#jumboid`?

In case you don't, you can easily fix it with a `background-image` on `#jumboid`.

Edit the css as following:

```
#jumboid{
    width:100% ;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(http://www.visitnorwich.co.uk/assets/Uploads/Events-images/Theatre-generic.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

(forked) example: https://codepen.io/pimskie/pen/wGPOar

Answer (score 1):

Simply use, using `contain` keeps your bg-img scalable and responsive-

`background-size:contain;`

OR if want to have a fixed header height and wan't to keep the image background  scaled upto header's width-

`background-size:100% 100%;`

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this code and Is this what you are looking for.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#jumboid {
  width: 100%;
}
.bg-image {
  position: relative;
  background: url("http://www.visitnorwich.co.uk/assets/Uploads/Events-images/Theatre-generic.jpg") no-repeat center center /cover;
  height: 450px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.bg-image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 1px);
  background-image: url('a.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://www.jqueryscript.net/css/jquerysctipttop.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="sltac.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="bg-image" id="jumboid">
      </div>

    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="restofthecontent">
    <p>your content</p>
  </div>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but half of the image also removed in your implementation

Answer (score 0):

Put your image in background of DIV by css not in `<img>` tag.

and give that DIV below CSS.

```css
.Your_DV {
 background-image: url(http://www.visitnorwich.co.uk/assets/Uploads/Events-images/Theatre-generic.jpg);
background-position: fixed;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```